# Distribution forces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, statics, string

I've got two trees and between them is a rope. When someone about 100kg sits at the center of the rope, what are the forces on both parts of rope (to the left-hand side from the person and right-hand side)? When no-one is sitting on the rope, the angle between rope and ground is 0 degrees. When he sits, it is about 15 to 20 degrees.

And how can I compute that?

Comment: Hint: A tension $T$ acting at an angle $\theta$ has a vertical component of $T\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't know. I suppose I will use sin(15°). But how to combine that with weight?

Comment: Forces must balance. So the vertical downward force (your weight) must equal the vertical upward force...

Answer (score 1):

Since the length of the rope must remain constant the trees must bend towards the center on both sides .

If the mass of the person is M , then by balancing forces in vertical

Mg = 2.T.sin(theta) : theta being angle ~20 degrees